# How do i create a Matrix without importing Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np


Matrix

A = np.array ([[0.23,0.11,0.6], [0.4,0.35,0,5],[0.05,0.2,0.75]])
b = np.array([[1],[5],[5]])

##GAUSSIAN ELIMINATION

AugmentedMatrix = np.hstack([A, b.reshape(-1, 1)])
print(AugmentedMatrix)

n = len(b)

for i in range(n):
    a = AugmentedMatrix[i]

    for j in range(i + 1, n):
        b = AugmentedMatrix[j]
        m = a[i] / b[i]
        AugmentedMatrix[j] = a - m * b

for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
    AugmentedMatrix[i] = AugmentedMatrix[i] / AugmentedMatrix[i, i]
    a = AugmentedMatrix[i]

    for j in range(i - 1, -1, -1):
        b = AugmentedMatrix[j]
        m = a[i] / b[i]
        AugmentedMatrix[j] = a - m * b

x = AugmentedMatrix[:, 3]

print ("X1 =",x[0])
print ("X2 =",x[1])
print ("X3 =",x[2])
```

Basically, i cannot use numpy in this equation. Any tips on how to create array without it? i've tried using list of lists but got an error of
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: If you don't use numpy, you need to write your own functions for doing arithmetic with matrixes.

Comment: There's no easy way to do this. You'd basically have to reimplement all the parts of numpy you care about, in particular arithmetic operations where one operand is an array and the other is a number .

Comment: You can just use a list of lists, but that will not be a "matrix" in the sense that you can use e.g. matrix multiplication and other operations. For that, you will need `numpy` (or a similar library)

Comment: Sure you can use lists of lists.  You just have to use a list comprehension  (or other iteration) to do things like element-wise multiplication (and addition).  That's just basic Python.  With loops on `i` and `j` this code is already doing list like operations.  Come to think of it, we should down vote this because mentions an error, but does not identify where (i.e. traceback).  If you want help, provide full information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have made small mistake...
I went out and implemented some matrix/scalar operations in a simple class.
Then I looked at this task and realized there are mostly row operations.
I dont have time to rewrite the class so the main solution looks junky.
Matrix class:

```py
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, list_of_lists):
        if isinstance(list_of_lists, Matrix):
            self.matrix = list_of_lists.matrix.copy()
        elif not isinstance(list_of_lists, list):
            raise ValueError("Not a list")
        elif not all((isinstance(x, list) for x in list_of_lists)):
            raise ValueError("Element of main list is not a list")
        elif not all((type(y) in [int, float] for x in list_of_lists for y in x)):
            raise ValueError("Element of sub list is not a number")
        else:
            self.matrix = list_of_lists

    def __len__(self):
        return max(len(self.matrix), len(self.matrix[0]))

    def __str__(self):
        s = [[str(e) for e in row] for row in self.matrix]
        lens = [max(map(len, col)) for col in zip(*s)]
        fmt = (' '*2).join('{{:{}}}'.format(x) for x in lens)
        table = [fmt.format(*row) for row in s]
        return str('\n'.join(table))

    def size(self):
        return len(self.matrix), len(self.matrix[0])

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def __getitem__(self, row):
        return self.matrix[row]

    def __setitem__(self, row, data):
        self.matrix[row] = data

    def __internal_scalar_operation(self, row_number, scalar_value, operator):
        if operator == '+':
            self[row_number] = [float(x + scalar_value) for x in self[row_number]]
        elif operator == '-':
            self[row_number] = [float(x-scalar_value) for x in self[row_number]]
        elif operator == '*':
            self[row_number] = [float(x*scalar_value) for x in self[row_number]]
        elif operator == '/':
            self[row_number] = [float(x/scalar_value) for x in self[row_number]]

    def scalar_row_add(self, row_number, scalar_value):
        self.__internal_scalar_operation(row_number, scalar_value, '+')
    def scalar_row_sub(self, row_number, scalar_value):
        self.__internal_scalar_operation(row_number, scalar_value, '-')
    def scalar_row_mul(self, row_number, scalar_value):
        self.__internal_scalar_operation(row_number, scalar_value, '*')
    def scalar_row_div(self, row_number, scalar_value):
        self.__internal_scalar_operation(row_number, scalar_value, '/')

    def __internal_row_operation(self, row_number, row, operator):
        if not len(self[row_number]) == len(row):
            raise ArithmeticError("Matrices with not same dimensions")
        if operator == '+':
            self[row_number] = [float(x + y) for x, y in zip(self[row_number], row)]
        elif operator == '-':
            self[row_number] = [float(x - y) for x, y in zip(self[row_number], row)]
        elif operator == '*':
            self[row_number] = [float(x * y) for x, y in zip(self[row_number], row)]
        elif operator == '/':
            self[row_number] = [float(x / y) for x, y in zip(self[row_number], row)]

    def row_add_row(self, row_number, row):
        self.__internal_row_operation(row_number, row, '+')
    def row_sub_row(self, row_number, row):
        self.__internal_row_operation(row_number, row, '-')
    def row_mul_row(self, row_number, row):
        self.__internal_row_operation(row_number, row, '*')
    def row_div_row(self, row_number, row):
        self.__internal_row_operation(row_number, row, '/')

    def append_column(self, matrix_column):
        for idx, row in enumerate(matrix_column):
            self.matrix[idx].append(*row)
```

and the main

```py
m1 = Matrix([[0.05,0.55,0.25], [0.9,0.25,0],[0.05,0.2,0.75]])
m2 = Matrix([[2],[6],[2]])
m1.append_column(m2)
xn = len(m2)

for i in range(xn):
    for j in range(i + 1, xn):
        mm = m1[i][i] / m1[j][i]
        tmp1 = Matrix(m1)
        tmp2 = Matrix(m1)
        tmp2.scalar_row_mul(j, mm)
        tmp1.row_sub_row(i, tmp2[j])
        m1[j] = tmp1[i]

for i in range(xn - 1, -1, -1):
    m1.scalar_row_div(i, m1[i][i])
    for j in range(i - 1, -1, -1):
        tmp1 = Matrix(m1)
        tmp2 = Matrix(m1)
        mm = m1[i][i] / tmp2[j][i]
        tmp2.scalar_row_mul(j, mm)
        tmp1.row_sub_row(i, tmp2[j])
        m1[j] = tmp1[i]

print(m1)
```

final result looks good

```py
1.0   -0.0  -0.0  6.01562500000001 
-0.0  1.0   -0.0  2.343749999999999
0.0   0.0   1.0   1.640625
```